# Overriding sequence with visual designer?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I'd like to extend the Sequence activity with my own, including a few dropdown options that show up in the designer.. I've found some disjointed tutorials, but nothing that really makes alot of sense.. Is the a clear guide on how to build a custom action that's got a designer and can host other activities internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [WorkflowItemsPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.design.workflowitemspresenter.aspx) along with the **Activity Designer** item template to provide a container activity capable of hosting multiple children activities. MSDN provides an example in their WF and WCF [samples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744850.aspx). To provide an container activity that hosts a single child activity, you would use [WorkflowItemPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowitempresenter.aspx).